# Let $z$ be the complex number $7-3i$, find a complex number $w$ such that $zw$ is a negative real number

Tags: complex-numbers

I feel a bit bad asking this question but here it goes:

My initial idea was to rotate the complex number $z$ onto the negative real axis and then compute what complex number was used to do that but that feels a bit too long-winded for this type of problem, I was wondering if anyone has a shortcut.

Comment: Can you find some $w$ such that $zw$ is a positive real number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $z^\ast$ be the conjugate of $z$.

$$zz^\ast=|z|^2$$

Let $a$ be any negative number.
$$z(az^\ast)=a|z|^2$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Let $w = a + bi$. Then their product can be written as
\begin{align*}
(7-3i)(a + bi) = 7a + 3b + (7b - 3a)i
\end{align*}

Since $zw$ is a negative number, its imaginary part must equal zero and its real part must be negative.

More precisely, we have the following system
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
7b - 3a = 0\\\\
7a + 3b < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?